The Hydra Game runs forever
I saw this question here: The Hydra Game algorithm
I am also running into troubles with the same problem.
I also learned of the problem in this Numberphile video, and also tried to compute it myself.
The problem with my code is that it runs forever for n=4. It produces the correct results for n=1-3. I have had it running for about 3 hours now, and it is still running.
Here is my code:
class Node:
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.children = []

def is_root(self):
    return self.parent == None

def add_child(self):
    self.children.append(Node(self))

def chop(self, n = 2):
    if not self.parent.is_root():
        for i in range(n):
            self.parent.parent.add_child()
    self.parent.children.remove(self)

def find_leftmost(self):
    if len(self.children) > 0:
        return self.children[-1].find_leftmost()
    return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(None)
    root.add_child()
    root.children[0].add_child()
    root.children[0].children[0].add_child()
    root.children[0].children[0].children[0].add_child()

    steps = 0
    while len(root.children) > 0:
        root.find_leftmost().chop(steps+1)
        steps += 1

    print(steps)


What makes you think it's running forever? If you periodically print steps, have you seen it pass 938038?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Programming questions are off-topic here.

A nice little rule when having these types of problems: 'When in doubt, print it out'
But if it is hanging, it is because of while len(root.children) > 0: root.children may never actually be reaching a length of 0.
